# Knife tool perpendicular cut

Tags: modeling, add-on

While working in maya for a long time, i'm slowly start to explore blender and adore it tools, but when i start using **knife tool** i couldn't find an option that been used all the time in work, and it's making **90 degrees** cuts without switching into ortho views or align view to the face or an edge T_T. There are couple of old threads about it, and it's really bugging me why this simple and very handy option still not implemented? Is there an addon for it?

**update**: i have added a gif for a better representation of what i'm looking for
[image]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: What's wrong with ortho view, align to face?  There are a lot of operations in blender that operate in view space, and knowing your view manipulation tools is important to using them well.  Maybe if we knew what was wrong with changing your view, we could offer workflow suggestions that would address that complaint?

Comment: hey Nathan, this is something that stops someone who works in other 3d packages for a long time and want to switch to blender, when a simple tool that covers a big percentage of work can perform the same task only with a multiple additional clicks. And overall this function exists in all the different software's i worked in.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this in blender. Its not as good as the one on maya (as much as I hate to say it...) but it works

Now this is on a mac so the shortcut is different

So here is a picture of the very bottom of your screen when you use the knife tool:
[image]

[image]

In the middle you should see something that says midpoint snap. This snaps your cursor to the middle of the nearest edge. The shortcut will be to the right side of the text. For me, it is the symbol ^/^ (which is control on mac) When you use it, it will only connect to the middles of edges, so it is basically 90 degree tool. Once you do this, use an edge slide (press g twice while an edge is selected) and move it to your desired location

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! thanks for respond. Yeah it was surprising for me that maya do it better, unfortunately middle point is rarely help in this situations. I really hope blender will have this feature in the arsenal someday

Comment: Yep, as much as I hate to say it, Maya gets a point for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand the question but ... when in Knife mode you can use the shortcut "c" to constrain the cut to 45 or 90 degrees. There are other keystrokes that help with the knife too.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html
Hope this helps.
Daf

Comment: Hello! this constraint only works in the screen projection mode, what i'm looking for is to make straight angle cuts without aligning the camera view to component each time i need it, example in the link
https://dropmefiles.com/K1R02

Answer (score 0):

Found out that if I start a knife cut [K] on an edge then press the axis key [X, Y, Z] I want to cut on, I can cut in a straight line without having to cut through the entire mesh. Anywhere along the axis you are cutting the straight line, press a different axis key [X, Y, Z] to switch directions for a straight knife cut along that axis and so on.